# What determines the output javascript file name generated by scalajs sbt plugin?

Tags: npm, sbt, npm-install, scala.js

In this project:

https://github.com/tribbloid/scalajs-cli-demo

I defined a scalajs project using a combination of npm and sbt, inside npm package file I declare sbt as a prepublish script:

```
  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": "sbt 'show fullOptJS' && cp target/scala-2.12/scalajs-cli-demo-opt.js ./lib/main.js",
    "test": "sbt test"
  },
```

The sbt build definition use scalajs sbt plugin to pull dependencies and invoke transpiler(s):

```
resolvers += Resolver.sonatypeRepo("releases")
enablePlugins(ScalaJSPlugin)
name := "Scala.js CLI Demo first release"
scalaVersion := "2.12.7"
scalaJSModuleKind := ModuleKind.CommonJSModule
scalaJSUseMainModuleInitializer := true
mainClass in Compile := Some("HelloWorldApp")

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.scalajs/nodejs
libraryDependencies += "io.scalajs" %%% "nodejs" % "0.4.2"

moduleName in fullOptJS := "scalajs-cli-demo"
```

However, when I run `npm install`, I got the following error information in the log:

```
67 info lifecycle scalajs-cli-demo@1.0.4~prepublish: Failed to exec prepublish script
68 verbose stack Error: scalajs-cli-demo@1.0.4 prepublish: `sbt 'show fullOptJS' && cp target/scala-2.12/scalajs-cli-demo-opt.js ./lib/main.js`
68 verbose stack Exit status 1
68 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:301:16)
68 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:182:13)
68 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
68 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
68 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:962:16)
68 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:251:5)
69 verbose pkgid scalajs-cli-demo@1.0.4
70 verbose cwd /home/peng/git-release/scalajs-cli-demo
71 verbose Linux 4.19.11-041911-generic
72 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
73 verbose node v10.14.2
74 verbose npm  v6.4.1
75 error code ELIFECYCLE
76 error errno 1
77 error scalajs-cli-demo@1.0.4 prepublish: `sbt 'show fullOptJS' && cp target/scala-2.12/scalajs-cli-demo-opt.js ./lib/main.js`
77 error Exit status 1
78 error Failed at the scalajs-cli-demo@1.0.4 prepublish script.
78 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
79 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Further investigation shows that the file in cp command `target/scala-2.12/scalajs-cli-demo-opt.js` doesn't exist.

Instead the file is named `scala-js-cli-demo-opt.js`, however I cannot find it anywhere in scalajs sbt plugin that defines this file name. In fact, the name `scala-js-cli-demo` doesn't even exist anywhere in my source code! So how does scalajs sbt plugin derive this file name? And what should I do to correct it?

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the general useful keys that determine the name of the resulting artifact: `name`, `normalizedName` (which replaces unallowed symbols with dashes), `moduleName` and `artifactName`, you can also override where the compiled `.js` file is placed and how it will be called (despite all those name-related settings) using the `artifactPath` setting. For example:

```
Compile / fullOptJS / artifactPath := baseDirectory.value / "lib" / "main.js"
```

or the same with `fastOptJS`.

Answer (score 0):

OK I have figure out myself, the name is generated from project name/artifactID. In this case it simply replaced all irregular characters into dashes.